# Color and movement of OpenGL object does not alternate properly

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math, light

My program is a room with a light source in the center (the sphere).

[image]

I want to make a "disco" mode that will make the sphere move left and right along the x-axis. And also alternate its color between red and blue at the same time.

This is the section of my code that enables the mode. `g_disco_mode` is the variable that is true once the mode is chosen.

```
static void update_scene()
{
    ...

    // Disco mode
    if (g_disco_mode)
    {
        bool movement_increase = true;
        bool color_increase = true;
        float floor = -0.1f;
        float ceiling = 1.0f;
        float increment = 0.01f;

        // Movement of spotlight
        if (movement_increase == true && g_lightProperties.direction[0] <= ceiling)
        {
            g_lightProperties.direction[0] += increment;

            if (g_lightProperties.direction[0] >= ceiling) { movement_increase = false; }
        }

        if (movement_increase == false && g_lightProperties.direction[0] >= floor)
        {
            g_lightProperties.direction[0] -= increment;

            if (g_lightProperties.direction[0] <= floor) { movement_increase = true; }
        }

        // Changing of color
        g_spotlight_ambient[0] += 0.01f;

        if (color_increase == true && g_spotlight_ambient[0] <= ceiling)
        {
            g_spotlight_ambient[0] += increment;

            if (g_spotlight_ambient[0] >= ceiling) { color_increase = false; }
        }

        if (color_increase == false && g_spotlight_ambient[0] >= floor)
        {
            g_spotlight_ambient[0] -= increment;

            if (g_spotlight_ambient[0] <= floor) { color_increase = true; }
        }   
    }
}
```

I wrote this section of code such that the sphere will move right until it hits the `ceiling` and then move left until it hits the `floor`. This is done by incrementing and decrementing `g_lightProperties.direction`.
The changing of color works in a similar way as well. However, when I run my program, the sphere moves right until it hits the `ceiling` and then stops. It does not move move to the left. For the color, it just keeps on turning red and does not go back to blue. Why is that so?

My program

```
// Values for spotlight
glm::vec3 g_spotlight_ambient(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
glm::vec3 g_spotlight_diffuse(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glm::vec3 g_spotlight_specular(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

bool g_switchOn = true;     // toggle the light on/off
bool g_disco_mode = false;  // makes the lights move around and change color

static void init(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    ...

// initialise light and material properties
    g_lightProperties.position = glm::vec4(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.ambient = glm::vec4(g_spotlight_ambient[0], g_spotlight_ambient[1], g_spotlight_ambient[2], 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.diffuse = glm::vec4(g_spotlight_diffuse[0], g_spotlight_diffuse[1], g_spotlight_diffuse[2], 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.specular = glm::vec4(g_spotlight_specular[0], g_spotlight_specular[1], g_spotlight_specular[2], 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.shininess = 10.0f;
    g_lightProperties.attenuation = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    g_lightProperties.cutoffAngle = 100.0f;
    g_lightProperties.direction = glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

    ...
}

// function used to update the scene
static void update_scene()
{
    static float rotateAngle = 0.0f;
    static float cutOffAngle = g_lightProperties.cutoffAngle;

    rotateAngle -= 1.0f;

    // update model matrix
    g_modelMatrix_mesh[0] = glm::rotate(glm::radians(rotateAngle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
            * glm::translate(glm::vec3(-0.4f, 0.1f, 0.0f)) * glm::scale(glm::vec3(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f));
    g_modelMatrix_mesh[1] = glm::rotate(glm::radians(rotateAngle), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f))
            * glm::translate(glm::vec3(0.4f, 0.3f, 0.0f)) * glm::scale(glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
    g_modelMatrix_mesh[2] = glm::translate(g_lightProperties.direction)
            * glm::translate(glm::vec3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f)) * glm::scale(glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));

    // update spotlight
    g_lightProperties.ambient = glm::vec4(g_spotlight_ambient[0], g_spotlight_ambient[1], g_spotlight_ambient[2], 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.diffuse = glm::vec4(g_spotlight_diffuse[0], g_spotlight_diffuse[1], g_spotlight_diffuse[2], 1.0f);
    g_lightProperties.specular = glm::vec4(g_spotlight_specular[0], g_spotlight_specular[1], g_spotlight_specular[2], 1.0f);

    // Disco mode
    if (g_disco_mode)
    {
        bool movement_increase = true;
        bool color_increase = true;
        float floor = -0.1f;
        float ceiling = 1.0f;
        float increment = 0.01f;

        // Movement of spotlight
        if (movement_increase == true && g_lightProperties.direction[0] <= ceiling)
        {
            g_lightProperties.direction[0] += increment;

            if (g_lightProperties.direction[0] >= ceiling) { movement_increase = false; }
        }

        if (movement_increase == false && g_lightProperties.direction[0] >= floor)
        {
            g_lightProperties.direction[0] -= increment;

            if (g_lightProperties.direction[0] <= floor) { movement_increase = true; }
        }

        // Changing of color
        g_spotlight_ambient[0] += 0.01f;

        if (color_increase == true && g_spotlight_ambient[0] <= ceiling)
        {
            g_spotlight_ambient[0] += increment;

            if (g_spotlight_ambient[0] >= ceiling) { color_increase = false; }
        }

        if (color_increase == false && g_spotlight_ambient[0] >= floor)
        {
            g_spotlight_ambient[0] -= increment;

            if (g_spotlight_ambient[0] <= floor) { color_increase = true; }
        }   
    }

}

// function used to render the scene
static void render_scene()
{
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO[0]);        // make VAO active

// Material Properties - Planes
    glUniform4fv(g_materialAmbientIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties.ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties.diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_materialSpecularIndex, 1, &g_materialProperties.specular[0]);

    glUniform4fv(g_lightPositionIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.position[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_lightAmbientIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.ambient[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_lightDiffuseIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.diffuse[0]);
    glUniform4fv(g_lightSpecularIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.specular[0]);
    glUniform1fv(g_lightShininessIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.shininess);
    glUniform3fv(g_lightAttenuationIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.attenuation[0]);
    glUniform1fv(g_lightCutoffAngleIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.cutoffAngle);
    glUniform3fv(g_lightDirectionIndex, 1, &g_lightProperties.direction[0]);

    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    TwBar *TweakBar;            // pointer to a tweak bar

    ...

    // initialise AntTweakBar
    TwInit(TW_OPENGL_CORE, NULL);

    // give tweak bar the size of graphics window
    TwWindowSize(g_windowWidth, g_windowHeight);
    TwDefine(" TW_HELP visible=false ");    // disable help menu
    TwDefine(" GLOBAL fontsize=3 ");        // set large font size

    // create a tweak bar
    TweakBar = TwNewBar("Main");
    TwDefine(" Main label='Controls' refresh=0.02 text=light size='220 600' ");

    // create display entries
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "Wireframe", TW_TYPE_BOOLCPP, &g_wireFrame, " group='Display' ");

    // display a separator
    TwAddSeparator(TweakBar, NULL, NULL);

    // create spotlight entries
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "Cutoff", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_lightProperties.cutoffAngle, " group='Spotlight' min=-180.0 max=180.0 step=1.0 ");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "Direction: x", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_lightProperties.direction[0], " group='Spotlight' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.1");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "Direction: y", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_lightProperties.direction[1], " group='Spotlight' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.1");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "Direction: z", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_lightProperties.direction[2], " group='Spotlight' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.1");
    // create transformation entries
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "A Red", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_ambient[0], " group='Ambient' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "A Green", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_ambient[1], " group='Ambient' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "A Blue", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_ambient[2], " group='Ambient' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");

    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "D Red", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_diffuse[0], " group='Diffuse' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "D Green", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_diffuse[1], " group='Diffuse' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "D Blue", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_diffuse[2], " group='Diffuse' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");

    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "S Red", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_specular[0], " group='Specular' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "S Green", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_specular[1], " group='Specular' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "S Blue", TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &g_spotlight_specular[2], " group='Specular' min=-1.0 max=1.0 step=0.01");

    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "Light", TW_TYPE_BOOLCPP, &g_switchOn, " group='Toggle ON/OFF' ");
    TwAddVarRW(TweakBar, "Disco", TW_TYPE_BOOLCPP, &g_disco_mode, " group='Toggle ON/OFF' ");

    // initialise rendering states
    init(window);

    // the rendering loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        g_camera.update(window);    // update camera

        if (g_wireFrame)
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        update_scene();     // update the scene
        render_scene();     // render the scene

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

        TwDraw();           // draw tweak bar(s)

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);    // swap buffers
        glfwPollEvents();           // poll for events
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second if be ` && g_lightProperties.direction[0] >= floor`? Otherwise this will only be called once.

Comment: @BDL thanks for pointing that out. I changed it in my code but it still has the same problem

Comment: In the nested if: `movement_increase == false;` should be `movement_increase = false;`. Please debug your code yourself. We are not here to do your work for you. Print out what happens or set breakpoints and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test whether the *ceiling* or the *floor* is reached and then you have to change the direction

Your code should look somehow like this:

```
if ( movement_increase )
{   
    // if less than ceiling keep increasing
    movement_increase = g_lightProperties.direction[0] < ceiling; 
}
else
{
    // if less or equal floor change to increasing
    movement_increase = g_lightProperties.direction[0] <= floor;
}
g_lightProperties.direction[0] += movement_increase ? increment : -increment; 

if ( color_increase )
    color_increase = g_spotlight_ambient[0] < 1.0;
else
    color_increase = g_spotlight_ambient[0] <= 0.0;
g_spotlight_ambient[0] += color_increase  ? increment : -increment;
```

Apart from that the variables `movement_increase` and `color_increase` are local variables, so they will be initialized every continuously. Either you use global varibales or you delcare them `static`:

```
 static bool movement_increase = true;
 static bool color_increase = true;
```

Comment: thanks rabbid, i tried it but it yields the same result as before